# Passing token through $_SESSION and $_POST - if statement issues?

Tags: php, forms, session, csrf

I'm implementing CSRF protection and have had a really hard time. So I generate a token and store it in the `$_SESSION['token']`. Now I'm going to need this token for comparison on another page, so on the other page I do this:

```
session_start();
$token = "";
$token = $_SESSION['token'];
echo $token;

unset($_SESSION['token']);
echo "<br />";

$compToken = "";
$compToken = $_POST['token'];
echo $compToken;
```

PHP requires me to set the variables to something, or else it is invalid. Here is the output to that:

```
41852450b2fbeed352d895d8ee57dfc9
41852450b2fbeed352d895d8ee57dfc9
```

As you can see, they are matching tokens. Now when I come down to the if statement to compare what I just grabbed from the form before I proceed to processing:

```
if($compToken === $token) {
    return true;
} else {
    echo "Token error.";
    return false;
}
```

It just doesn't work, no errors reported either. I even tried `if($_SESSION['token'] === $_POST['token'])`, which should work since both variables were successfully passed and stored (as shown in the previous code).

What is happening with the `if statement`?

EDIT:

```
session_start();
$token = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
$_SESSION["token"] = $token;
```

Ok, the part below is a mess - for debugging purposes. Sorry!

```
session_start();
$token = "";
$token = $_SESSION['token'];
$token = trim($token);
echo $token;
unset($_SESSION['token']);
echo "<br />";
$compToken = "";
$compToken = $_POST['token'];
$compToken = trim($compToken);
echo $compToken;
echo "<br />";
echo"1";
if($compToken == $token) {
    return true;
} else {
    echo "Token error.";
    return false;
}
echo "2";
```

EDIT2:

For those reading this in the future, it seems the issue was returning true for the if statement in the original `edit`. I am not sure why - but changing that to just `echo "true";` seems to work. I'm going to adjust the `if statement` to only `return false; and die();` if they do not equal each other.

Comment: try trim($compToken) as there might be spaces wrap accidentally

Comment: @Sunand Didn't seem to work, both strings are in fact equal in terms of whitespace.

Comment: Have you tried `$compToken == $token`? Just a thought.

Comment: @jboneca Yes, I was thinking that may be the problem as well but it wasn't the case. I tried it going both ways. I can't for the life of me figure out what is wrong - I just know it is at the `if statement` from debugging techniques.

Comment: Edit your question to include the code from page where you set `$_SESSION['token']`

Comment: It should be in there, the top part is from the form page and the second code is from the processing page (if I understand correctly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried it did you make sure you have this in your form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?=$_SESSION['token'];?>" />
```

Here is my code:
form.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['token'] = 'abc123abc123';

?>

<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="abc123abc123" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

This is where the form posts to:
index.php

```
<?php

session_start();
$token = $_SESSION['token'];

$compToken = $_POST['token'];

if($compToken === $token) {
    echo 'True';
} else {
    echo "Token error.";
}
```

And it echos out 'True'.

Comment: I actually have this in my form: `<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $token; ?>"/>`. Does it make a difference? I tried yours and it seems to not work with no explanation as well.

Comment: Should not make a difference...  any more info you can give for us to help?

Comment: Do you have session_start(); on both pages?

Comment: Yes, I have session_start() on both pages. Unfortunately there isn't much else to give - let me edit my original post and put all the code there.

Comment: Okay so I just copied everything you put up and pasted it into my two files and it works... I just changed return true to echo 'True' so it prints out 'True' if it works.

Comment: That's very odd, it does work after I changed that. If I return true does that mean that the program has finished or something? Maybe I'll edit the `if statement` to say that if they aren't equal, then `die()`. That would work and avoid me having to return true/false. Thank you very much Brandon!